# Is there a way to force US keyboard layout in Safari address bar?

Tags: macos, keyboard, safari, safari-extensions

I keep typing in Russian keyboard layout into Safari address bar by accident.
This drives me mad because I usually end up loading domain-for-sale pages.

[image]

Is there an extension or program to **switch keyboard layout to US on <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>** before letting me enter the URL?

Comment: Just to clarify, are you looking to invoke the Command + Space function (switching to next input source) while using Command + L?

Comment: No. I don't need to switch to *next* input source, I need to switch to a *specific* input source. This is exactly my problem: I don't remember which input source was last selected when I press Cmd+L, and there is just no sense in it being other than US English for location bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, there is a program called [**Punto Switcher**](http://punto.yandex.ru/) that does exactly that.

[image: Punto Switcher]

It puts a global hook on keyboard events and triggers automatic input switch (which is configurable) as soon as it detects nonsense being typed. Rather than relying on application types and input fields, it uses a dictionary (e.g. `пщщпдуюсщь` is recognized as mistyped `google.com`).

It also has a neat feature of “transcoding” mistyped words into another layout by pressing <kbd>⌥</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using exactly two keyboard layouts, you can toggle between them with Command-Space if it is activated in the **Language & Text** System Preference. With that enabled, perhaps you could write a macro or Applescript to invoke that command along with Command-L.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I do constantly use Cmd+Space, the issue is with adjusting to precisely US layout *automatically*. How do I write an AppleScript to be invoked only in Safari on pressing Cmd+L?

Comment: I am hoping that someone else here can help you with that. I'm not proficient with AppleScript!